# Test My Restful Web Service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a few tests of my CRUD operations in my springboot Restful Web Service, but I can't, because every tutorial I follow ends up with some error !
This time I'm publishing this in order to get some help from you.
My CloudProduct.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.sql.Date;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="cloud_product_info")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE cloud_product_info SET deleted = true WHERE product_id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
//@FilterDef(name="", parameters = @ParamDef(name="isDeleted", type = "boolean"))
//@Filter(name="deletedBookFilter", condition = "deleted = :isDeleted")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, 
        allowGetters = true)



public class CloudProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer productId;

    private String productName;
    private Float priceInEuros;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    private Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;


    @JsonIgnore
    public Boolean getdeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public void setdeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public CloudProduct(Integer productId, String productName, Float priceInEuros) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.priceInEuros = priceInEuros;
    }

    public CloudProduct() {

    } 
    
    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public Float getpriceInEuros() {
        return priceInEuros;
    }
    public void setProductPrice(Float priceInEuros) {
        this.priceInEuros = priceInEuros;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + productId +
                ", name='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", price=" + priceInEuros +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My CloudProductController

```
package com.proj.my.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cloudproduct")

public class CloudProductController 
{

    CloudProductService cloudProductService;

    public CloudProductController(CloudProductService cloudProductService)
    {
        this.cloudProductService = cloudProductService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{productId}")
    public CloudProduct getCloudProductDetails(@PathVariable("productId") Integer productId){
        return cloudProductService.getCloudProduct(productId);
    }

    @GetMapping("getAll")
    public List<CloudProduct> getCloudProductDetails(){
        return cloudProductService.getCloudProducts();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String createCloudProductDetails(@RequestBody CloudProduct cloudProduct){

        cloudProductService.createCloudProduct(cloudProduct);
        return "Success";
    }

    @PutMapping
    public CloudProduct updateCloudProductDetails(@RequestBody CloudProduct cloudProduct){

        return cloudProductService.updateCloudProduct(cloudProduct);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{productId}")
    public String deleteCloudProductDetails(@PathVariable("productId")Integer productId){

        cloudProductService.deleteCloudProduct(productId);
        return "Deleted!";
    }
    



}
```

My CloudProductServiceImpl.java

```
package com.proj.my.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;


@Service
public class CloudProductServiceImpl implements CloudProductService 
{

    CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    public CloudProductServiceImpl(CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository) {
    
        this.cloudProductRepository = cloudProductRepository;
    
    }

    @Override
    public String createCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct){
        cloudProductRepository.save(cloudProduct);
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    public CloudProduct updateCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct){
        CloudProduct existingCloudProductDetails = getCloudProduct(cloudProduct.getProductId());

        if(cloudProduct.getProductName() != null){
            existingCloudProductDetails.setProductName(cloudProduct.getProductName());
        }

        if(cloudProduct.getpriceInEuros() != null){
            existingCloudProductDetails.setProductPrice(cloudProduct.getpriceInEuros());
        }

        
        return cloudProductRepository.save(existingCloudProductDetails);
    }
        
    @Override
    public CloudProduct getCloudProduct(Integer cloudProductId){
        return cloudProductRepository.findById(cloudProductId).get();
    }


    @Override
    public String deleteCloudProduct(Integer cloudProductId){
        cloudProductRepository.deleteById(cloudProductId);
        return "Success";
    }

    
    @Override
    public List<CloudProduct> getCloudProducts()
    {
        return cloudProductRepository.findAll();
    }


    
}
```

My CloudProductService.java

```
package com.proj.my.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;

public interface CloudProductService {

    public String createCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct);
    public CloudProduct updateCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct);
    public String deleteCloudProduct(Integer cloudProductId);
    public CloudProduct getCloudProduct(Integer cloudProductId);
    public List<CloudProduct> getCloudProducts();
}
```

My cloudProductRepository.java

```
package com.proj.my.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;

public interface CloudProductRepository extends JpaRepository<CloudProduct, Integer> {
    
}
```

And finally, my CloudProductControllerTest.java

```
package com.proj.my.service.impl;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import com.proj.my.controller.CloudProductController;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import java.util.List;


@WebMvcTest(CloudProductController.class)
public class CloudProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    @MockBean
    private CloudProductService cloudProductService;

    @Test
    public void testgetCloudProductDetails() throws Exception{
        List<CloudProduct> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new CloudProduct(1, "Maria", (float) 232));
        productList.add(new CloudProduct(2, "Maria", (float) 232));
        Mockito.when(cloudProductRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(productList);

        String url = "";
        mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andExpect(status().isOk());
        String actualJsonResponse = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(actualJsonResponse);

        String expectedJsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productList);
        System.out.println(expectedJsonResponse);
        assertEquals(actualJsonResponse, expectedJsonResponse);

    }
}
```

And this test is wrong, because the expected here is "[]" and I'm getting " [{"productId":1,"productName":"Maria","priceInEuros":232.0,"createdAt":null},{"productId":2,"productName":"Maria","priceInEuros":232.0,"createdAt":null}]" which is correct... the expected is null, why ?

Comment: I think you try to create a GET request on an empty url. Try replacing the empty url with a valid endpoint like String url = "http://localhost:8080/cloudproduct/getAll";

Comment: Thanks sir, it worked perfectly for that, but I'm encountering now another obstacle...
I'm updating the question, thanks for the help.

Comment: You mock `CloudProductService` and do not call the real method (mock returns `null` by default), which is why `CloudProductRepository` mock is newer actually invoked.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying sir... what do I need to do here ? Thanks for your help

Comment: You dropped me this bomb and disappeared ahah I still need help guys

Comment: Empty url is not a good idea. You should use /cloudproduct/getAll as a url. Please try with this and share the result

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the problem with the test is that `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productList)` is returning "[]"?

Comment: Yes sir, it's returning []